# Azure CLI `AZ LOGIN` ERROR: "Found multiple accounts with the same username"

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, entra-id, accounts

I'm getting this error whenever I try to login to Azure via the CLI.  Here are the details:

```
PS C:\Users\MyName> az login  
Please select the account you want to log in with
```

***(Now I get a popup browser window where both accounts have the same username/email)***:
[image]

```
Found multiple accounts with the same username 'me@<redacted>.com': [{'home_account_id': 
'00000000-0000-0000-8413-<redacted>.9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-<redacted>', 'environment': 
'login.microsoftonline.com', 'username': 'me@<redacted>.com', 'authority_type': 'MSSTS',
 'local_account_id': 'ff37078a-25ee-4ca8-a555-<redacted>', 'realm': '2c5b6192-50ca-4e45-
869a-<redacted>'}, {'home_account_id': 'cd1796cb-a338-4267-8b6e-<redacted>.1a8ba571-a143
-461a-aac3-<redacted>', 'environment': 'login.microsoftonline.com', 'username':  'me@<re
dacted>.com', 'authority_type': 'MSSTS', 'local_account_id': 'cd1796cb-a338-4267-8b6e-<r
edacted>', 'realm': 'organizations'}]  
Please report to us via Github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/20168
```

1. The 2nd account (PERSONAL) is the one I am interested in using
2. **I have tried**:

   1. logging in multiple times -- **NO GO**
   2. the `az account clear` command from the PS prompt (to clear the cache)  -- **NO GO**
   3. checked to see if I am missing an MFA on my phone -- **NO GO**
   4. logging out via `az logout` and then logging back in via `az login` -- **NO GO**

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved this...

1. I logged into the portal directly at [portal.azure.com](https://portal.azure.com)
2. I clicked on Azure Active Directory (soon to be [Microsoft Entra ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/new-name))
3. I clicked on Manage Tenants [image]
4. This brings you to the default tenant, and there listed to the right of "tenant" is the tenant ID... you can copy that by clicking on the "copy icon"[image]
5. go back to the Azure CLI command prompt (either windows command prompt or powershell) and type `az login --tenant <your-tenant-id>`
6. you will get the BROWSER POPUP asking for the account you want to log in with, choose the correct account that holds your Azure subscription(s).
7. if you still have a problem try `az login --tenant <your-tenant-id> --use-device-code` which will force the browser to login using a code that the `az login` command prompt will supply in the command-line interface, which you then will enter into the browser (kind of like an MFA but pushed from the "device" [in this case your PC's command-line]).
8. this should log you in and list all subscriptions in your Microsoft Account which is the default behavior.
9. execute `az logout` and then log back in via `az login` (without any options/switches this time) and from this point forward this should be "fixed"